# PHP, array of jQuery objects into a PHP array, $.post and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamically created jQuery array that I am trying to post to the same page and turn into a PHP array. This is an example of what my array looks like:

```
var final_game = [];
[final_game { final_user_id="1",  final_game_id="1",  final_game_type="fun", final_price="1",  final_score="1.8"},final_game { final_user_id="1",  final_game_id="2",  final_game_type="fun", final_price="1",  final_score="2.8"}]
```

I am using this code to post it to the same page on click of a button:

```
$.post("http://www.samepage.com",{final_game: JSON.stringify(final_game)});
```

I then use this code to print the results to the page:

```
$data =  $_POST['final_game'];
print_r ( $data);
```

This outputs this string to the page:

```
[
{\"final_user_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_type\":\"fun\",\"final_price\":\"1\",\"final_score\":\"1.8\"},

{\"final_user_id\":\"2\",\"final_game_id\":\"2\",\"final_game_type\":\"fun\",\"final_price\":\"1\",\"final_score\":\"2.8\"}
]
```

Now I tried to use *json_decode*, but I wasn’t seeing anything displayed to the page. I think it may be because of the mixed content (string, int, decimal)? How can I transform this string into a usable PHP array?

Comment: first update to the correct code and send it without stringifying.

Comment: Shoot I forgot to include that in my example here, but I do have it in my code im working on.

Comment: without the stringifying I get a output of this:
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [final_user_id] => 1
           [final_game_id] => 2
           [final_game_type] => fun
           [final_price] => 1
           [final_score] => 2.8
       )

)

Comment: Looks like it came already decoded for you. There's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: So when I do something like this thou  $data =  $_POST['final_game'];
         print_r (  $data   ); all im getting on the page is "array"

Comment: An answer is used as an example in [an answer to a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425115/what-is-the-impact-of-the-moderation-strike/425372#425372) (the last of the five examples).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the unnecessary characters first with [stripslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```php
$data = $_POST['final_game'];
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: How is that (significantly) different from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173447/php-array-of-jquery-objects-into-a-php-array-post-and-json-stringify/76442163#76442163)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can adjust this  to this 

$.post("http://www.samepage.com", { final_game: final_game });

Answer (score -7):

**This will work for you,**

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['final_game'];
print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($data),true));

//best practice for decoding JSON.stringify:
//json_decode(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($data)),true);
?>
```

Comment: Don't know why people downvoted it. This is a PHP-side solution, however, the best solution is sending without stringifying.